# God does not stop delayed_job worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job, god

I need to monitor my delayed_job worker with god. It starts perfectly, but when i want to stop it using "sudo god stop dj" it says

```
Sending 'stop' command
The following watches were affected:
  dj-0
```

But worker is still on(it processes tasks etc.)

I looked through sites providing their god configs for delayed_job and stop command wasn't specified there. Do I need to specify stop task for god config or smth?

I start delayed_job with `w.start    = "cd #{rails_root} && QUEUE=work_server1 bundle exec rake -f #{rails_root}/Rakefile RAILS_ENV=#{environment} --trace jobs:work"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this problem. The reason was that using "bundle exec" two processes were spawned and god was monitoring the wrong one. So I've just upgraded rake to not use "bundle exec" and it works.

Comment: What do mean by 'upgrade rake'?

Comment: I'm encountering the same issue.  What do you mean by 'upgrade rake'?